# Best way to get max value in LINQ?

Tags: linq

I'm newbie to LINQ. I will like to get know what's the highest value for 'Date', which method is preferred?

```
var ma1x= spResult.Where(p =>p.InstrumentId== instrument).OrderByDescending(u => int.Parse(u.Date)).FirstOrDefault();
var max2= spResult.Where(p =>p.InstrumentId== instrument).Max(u => int.Parse(u.Date));
```

Max or OrderByDescending ?

Comment: If the `spResult.Date` property is of type DateTime, int.Parse(), should fail, because you cannot convert DateTime to Int32. You can however order by DateTime.Ticks, if you want or just by the property itself - without conversion

Comment: the `.Max<int>` LINQ extension throws Exception on empty source, but there are few alternatives around that

Answer (score 3):

## Max is better for both the developer and the computer.

`Max` will be always better because `Max` is semantic and meaningful.

> ## Enumerable.Max Method
>
> Returns the maximum value in a sequence of values.

[msdn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.max?view=netframework-4.7.2)

You want the max value? Use `Max`. You want to order? Use `OrderBy`. The next developer will thank you. To quote Martin Fowler:

> Any fool can write code that a computer can understand. Good programmers write code that humans can understand.

If you really want to use `OrderBy` to do the role of `Max` at least, wrap the orderby and the first in a method with a meaningful name. Something like ... `Max`. Great, now you have a meaningful OrderBy.

Lets see how this custom `Max` will do.

`Enumerable.Max` should be O(n) in the worst case when `OrderBy` use a quicksort which is O(n^2). So, the custom max is worst than the standard one...

Enjoy the performance bonus and go for `Enumerable.Max`. It is better for both the developer and the computer.

Edit:

Check Marco's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52851780/1248177) to see how they perform in practice. A [race of horses](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/) is always a nice idea to know which one is the faster.

Answer (score 1):

`.Max()` should be faster. First of all the semantics of the method are clearer and your colleagues will know what your call does.

I've compared both your options on the AdventureWorks2014 database, with the following calls in LinqPad:

```
var times = new List<long>();

for(var i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
    Stopwatch sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    var max2= SalesOrderHeaders.Max(u => u.OrderDate);
    long elapsed = sw.ElapsedMilliseconds;
    times.Add(elapsed);
}
var averageElapsed = times.Sum (t => t) / times.Count();
averageElapsed.Dump(" ms");
```

Generated SQL:

```
SELECT MAX([t0].[OrderDate]) AS [value]
FROM [Sales].[SalesOrderHeader] AS [t0]
GO
```

Result:

> 5 ms

```
var times = new List<long>();
for(var i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
    Stopwatch sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    var max1 = SalesOrderHeaders.OrderByDescending(u => u.OrderDate).FirstOrDefault();
    long elapsed = sw.ElapsedMilliseconds;
    times.Add(elapsed);
}
var averageElapsed = times.Sum (t => t) / times.Count();
averageElapsed.Dump(" ms");
```

Generated SQL:

```
SELECT TOP (1) [t0].[SalesOrderID], [t0].[RevisionNumber], [t0].[OrderDate], [t0].[DueDate], [t0].[ShipDate], [t0].[Status], [t0].[OnlineOrderFlag], [t0].[SalesOrderNumber], [t0].[PurchaseOrderNumber], [t0].[AccountNumber], [t0].[CustomerID], [t0].[SalesPersonID], [t0].[TerritoryID], [t0].[BillToAddressID], [t0].[ShipToAddressID], [t0].[ShipMethodID], [t0].[CreditCardID], [t0].[CreditCardApprovalCode], [t0].[CurrencyRateID], [t0].[SubTotal], [t0].[TaxAmt], [t0].[Freight], [t0].[TotalDue], [t0].[Comment], [t0].[rowguid] AS [Rowguid], [t0].[ModifiedDate]
FROM [Sales].[SalesOrderHeader] AS [t0]
ORDER BY [t0].[OrderDate] DESC
GO
```

Result:

> 28ms

Conclusion: `Max()` is more concise and faster!

Comment: Good old `race your horses` :) ([Eric Lippert on performance](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/))

Comment: This isn't quite going to give you the right answer, as the values his ordering by seem to be stored as strings... well it's the only reason I can see why he'd be using int.parse.

Comment: @Monofuse `int.Parse()` won't even compile, if `Date` is a DateTime object

Answer (score 0):

Purely speculative, but I'd imagine max2. It is just looping through each item and checking if the value is higher than the last. 
While max1 is checking which is higher and reordering. Even if it's just moving pointers around (rather than moving values), this is still more work.

Answer (score 0):

The `Max` method is better than `FirstOrDefault` both of them send a result as true, but the performance of Max is good.

This code:

```
var ma1x= spResult.Where(p =>p.InstrumentId== instrument).OrderByDescending(u => int.Parse(u.Date)).FirstOrDefault();
```

First check you condition, then sort them order by your condition, after that will be select and have more action to find your result.