# Get list of objects whose field has maximum value

Tags: c#, linq, sorting

Suppose I have this class

```
public class Person {
    public string name;
    public int age;
    //...
}
```

Suppose I have an array of Person:

```
Person[] personArray;
```

How can I get the list of Person with the biggest age within `personArray` using Linq?

---

I'm trying this but I wish there was a one-liner to perform this task:

```
public List<Person> GetBiggestAgeList(){
    var sortedPeople = personArray.OrderByDescending(person => person.age).ToList();
    int maxAge = sortedPeople[0].age;
    List<Person> answer = new List<Person>();
    for(int i = 0; i < sortedPeople.Count; ++i){
        if(sortedPeople[i].age == maxAge) answer.Add(sortedPeople[i]);
        else break;
    }
    return answer;
}
```

Comment: I don't need the first, I need the list of all Persons whose age is the same as the first. I'm trying to find a one-liner for that.

Comment: `personArray.Where(p1=>p1.Age == personArray.Max(p2=>p2.Age))`  One liner boom

Comment: @DanRayson just out of curiosity, I'm guessing writing it this way will perform a O(n) Max operation for each element, leading to a O(n²). Am I correct? I don't mind since my list will only have 4 elements, but it is good to know.

Comment: The proof https://dotnetfiddle.net/OZAJqJ

Comment: I have no idea, I'm a run it and see kinda guy.   Having said that, linq can be pretty smart.  ChatGPT answers the question "Would `personArray.Where(p1=>p1.Age == personArray.Max(p2=>p2.Age))` in C# linq cause O(n²) operations?" very nicely.

Comment: @DanRayson, the one-liner will be O(n²)

Comment: @KirillPolishchuk Only if linq doesn't compile down to a proper query under the hood, which it may.  If you wrote some linq for entity framework it'll compile it down to a sensible thing where it only checks Max once, I would expect the same from this, though I can't find any documentation on it.

Comment: @DanRayson, the example is clearly LINQ to objects

Comment: @DanRayson, https://dotnetfiddle.net/XkMfm3

Comment: @KirillPolishchuk Nice work :)  I clearly understood it was linq to objects xD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several options to accomplish this:

#### Option 1

---

using Linq `.Max()` [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.max?view=net-7.0)

```cs
// structured
var max = personArray.Max(inner => inner.Age);
var list = personArray.Where(p => p.Age == max);

// ...or in an one-liner
var list = personArray.Where(p => p.Age == personArray.Max(inner => inner.Age));
```

#### Option 2

---

using Linq `.GroupBy()` + `.FirstOrDefault()` [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/linq/group-query-results)

```cs
// this will first order your list 
// then group by all the ages and take the first group because this is the group of the persons with the highest age.
var list = personArray.OrderByDescending(p => p.Age)
                      .GroupBy(p => p.Age)
                      .FirstOrDefault()
                      .ToList();
```

Here you can find a working example [dotnet fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/HeIvXZ)

> I would recommand the Option 1 with the `.Max()` is more efficient and faster than Option 2 as you can see in the dotnet fiddle. To have it really fastest use Option 1 as two liner and resolve the `.Max()` first and then do the `.Where(..)`.

Comment: Eventually this SO Question can also help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52850917/best-way-to-get-max-value-in-linq

Answer (score 2):

One option would be

```
var opa = personArray.OrderByDescending(x=>x.age).FirstOrDefault();
```

to get all opas

```
var allOpas = personArray.Where(x=>x.age == opa.age);
```

One liner would be:

```
var allOpas2 = personArray.OrderByDescending(x=>x.age).GroupBy(x=>x.age).FirstOrDefault().ToList();
```

Comment: edited for that

Comment: Nitpick - I would group first, then order by key, then take the first group - I _think_ there will be less sorting that way.

Comment: Sorting is O(N log (N)). You can do this O(N) with a traditional `foreach` loop algorithm or with LINQ's `.Max`

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for a simple one-liner and don't mind adding an external dependency, **MoreLINQ** has an extension method (`MaxBy`) that will give you what you are looking for. [Documentation](https://morelinq.github.io/3.3/ref/api/html/M_MoreLinq_MoreEnumerable_MaxBy__2.htm)

```
var people = MoreLinq.MoreEnumerable.MaxBy(personArray, x => x.Age).ToArray();
```

Otherwise, the following one-liner will do the job.

```
var people = personArray.Where(x => x.Age == personArray.Max(x => x.Age)).ToArray();
```

Another option is to split it into two queries.

```
var max = personArray.Max(x => x.Age); // Find maximum age
var people = personArray.Where(x => x.Age == max).ToArray(); // Find people with maximum age
```